# Changing point color on hover in highcharts

Tags: highcharts, colors, hover, point

I want to change color of the columns which ever having value more than 25 on click of a button. I tried with changing the graphic attribute in the chart. Its working but I am facing one issue after update of the color. When I updated it for the first time some of the columns are reverting back to the original default color on mouseover. But after second time I clicked the button it's not happening. I have reproduced in this fiddle. 
http://jsfiddle.net/zDSeR/57/

```
    function returnColor(data){
    return '#e47ffe';
    }
    function changeColor(){
    var chartData = $('#container').highcharts();
    var a = chartData.series[0].data;
    for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
      if(a[i].y > 25){
      a[i].graphic.attr({'fill':'#000'});
      }
    }
}
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                zoomType: 'xy'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled:false       
                        }
                    }

                }
            },     
            series: [{
              type:'column',
              color:'#e47ffe',
              data:[100,20,40,50,42,78,98]
            }]
        });
    });
```

I know I can use point.update instead of graphic attribute, but I need alternate solution.

Please help.

Comment: What is it about point.update that you cannot use?

Comment: I am using highcharts 4.7.point.update is not working properly in that version color is updating but when clicked on particular legend its not getting hidden.

Comment: Then you need to handle this on legendItemClick event as well. So, you want to change a point's color to some value when you click on the point or some other button. Then, if you click on the highcharts legend items you want it to revert back to its original color?

Comment: Use [Zones](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.zones). Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/zDSeR/59/